# Brew can't install libav

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, libav

im trying to install libav using brew but it returns

`Error: libav has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!`

I've tried to follow [THIS](https://www.lyc4n.com/blog/2022/09/16/installing-unmaintained-brew-package.html) solution but im missing the `disable! date: "DATE", because: :unmaintained` line when editing the libav brew formula.

I've already tried reinstalling brew

brew version, 4.0.1-91-g6b7ecd1
macOS version, 13.1 (22C65)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it has been unmaintained for quite some time, see [this archive page](https://web.archive.org/web/20211022074004/https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-devel/2020-April/086589.html). This is [the related deprecation PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/81529), and homebrew usually disable the build after one year mark, which is usually the new release for macOS.

Comment: Gotcha! I’ve since adapted my script using ffmpeg, thanks for the awnser!

Comment: np, glad it works for you.